# Convert ASCII file to Decimal file

Tags: c#, file, decimal, ascii

Hello I have a textfile with (ASCII or other format i don't know maybe UTF or UNICODE) text. In this file are special letters. I want to convert all letters, the complete file into DECIMAL. I just don't know how.

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int size = -1;
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
    {
        string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        try
        {
            string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
            //call a function that converts the string text into decimal
            size = text.Length;
            memoEdit1.Text = text;
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(size); // <-- Shows file size in debugging mode.
    Console.WriteLine(result); // <-- For debugging use.
}
```

This is the Code so far...

UPDATE:

The File looks like this(ASCII or other format i don't know maybe UTF or UNICODE). This ist just sample (ASCII or other format i don't know maybe UTF or UNICODE) code.

ae ä
oe ö
ue ü
§
P
♀
! uæõ

and after the converting it should only be DECIMAL numbers.

For another example
The File looks like this (ASCII): äüö and after the converting it should look like this(DECIMAL): 228 252 246

Comment: Sorry... What exactly do you mean by converting it to decimal?

Comment: Indeed. Please add some sample input and output--an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: The File looks like this (ASCII): äüö and after the converting it should look like this(DECIMAL): 228 252 246

Comment: Please update your question with a short version of a sample size (so not 1000 lines of text) and the desired output, so that we don't have to search for it in the comments

Comment: it seems to me that your file is binary not ascii perhaps. If so, the first issue would be reading as ascii

Comment: That or the file is not ASCII, since the characters you supplied contain non-ASCII characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo that got that result:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string unconverted = "äüö"; // is what you get when using File.ReadAllText(file)

        byte[] converted = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(unconverted);

        converted = converted.Where(x => x != 0).ToArray(); //skip bytes that are 0

        foreach (var item in converted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick Answer Im trying to get your code working in my project

Answer (score 0):

Thanks now its working as I wanted it.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
```

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int size = -1;
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {
            string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            try
            {
                string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
                size = text.Length;

                //string unconverted = "äüö"; // is what you get when using File.ReadAllText(file)
                string unconverted = text;
                byte[] converted = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(unconverted);

                converted = converted.Where(x => x != 0).ToArray(); //skip bytes that are 0

                foreach (var item in converted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                    memoEdit1.Text =  memoEdit1.Text + item.ToString();
                    memoEdit1.Text = memoEdit1.Text + " "; //just for the Look and Feel :)
                }

               // memoEdit1.Text = text;
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(size); // <-- Shows file size in debugging mode.
        Console.WriteLine(result); // <-- For debugging use.
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Don't write answers if its not your own... instead accept the answer ... the other users will see that the issue is solved